# How to call a middlware on root route that serves static index.html files on nestjs?

Tags: node.js, angular, middleware, nestjs

I have situation where I need to call a middleware logic before HTML is served to restrict users based on locations. 
I am using Nest ServeStaticModule and I am unable to figure out a way to execute this middleware for only index.html. I want to call this middleware logic only on root route and any route which are prefixed by using 
app.setGlobalPrefix(globalPrefix);
needs to be ignored.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
We are using nrwl workspace for Angular + Nest development.

Comment: Nest has a lot of utilities for this. If you're doing some type of semi-complex logic, might I suggest guards: https://docs.nestjs.com/guards this will allow you to place a guard on your endpoint or class so that way it will do your logic before giving access to the resource.

Comment: I understand that guard will help me to protect routes but in that case I will have explicitly mention which routes to protect.By default nest attaches api prefix to every route. I don't want to allow node to load my angular application(which is loaded using static serve module) based on certain conditions.Is there any other way you suggest loading the angular application as static serve module does not give me adequate control to attach a guard/middleware.

Comment: Hmm... so you're serving the angular application which loads the system as a whole, but you want to restrict access to a subset, index.html, by some arbitrary rule?

Comment: index.html is responsible for bootstrapping my angular application.. but only if my pre conditions defined in middleware are met. As a work around I have triead approaches mentioned here https://whatthecode.dev/serve-static-files-with-nest-js/ but none of them seems to be working as expected.

Comment: So, why would a guard not work in this case? If you guard the route that gets called to load the HTML page, then you can shut down access before it ever gets there.

Comment: Yes @JarredParr I followed your advice and I found guard can be introduced. I was not using guard only because of the way I was serving my SPA. Now I have a middleware in place that takes care of serving my SPA.

Comment: @Vishal I have a similar issue. Which an auth-guard would not work for due to how the static assets are being served in middleware and not on a route. How did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone finding this question and looking to do something like OP said such as have some initial authentication check before serving up some static assets the following is my use case and solution.

**Use Case:**
I had a react app that I was attempting to serve up using NestJS. NestJS has a lot of ways to do this such as
https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mvc

```
app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'web', 'public'), {});
```

or by using the servestatic module they provide https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/serve-static.

**Problem:**
The above solutions provided by NestJS are all middleware and are served up before you ever hit a route so you can not catch the request and do authentication. You could

1. Add another middleware layer globally that checks authentication for the landing page before serving the assets, however the issue with this is that global middleware must be functional middleware and you can not use dependencies such as the config service or auth service which I needed/wanted
2. add a default route such as `/` but I found the middleware returned the static assets before that route would even be hit
3. You could define a route to serve up the index.html file instead of using the serve static assets but when I did this I hit errors such as `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' serving in nestjs` This was due to some of the assets not being accessible and only the index.html file being accessed.

**Solution:**
Serve the static assets using middleware for everything except the index file, for that use a route and do the check for authentication there before that index file reaches out for other assets. The way to do this is with the ServeStaticOption `index:false` which will mean the index.html is not sent back as default and instead will allow for the route to return that.

main.ts

```
app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'web', 'public'), {index: false});
```

app.controller.ts

```
  @Get('/')
  index(@Res() res: Response,@Next() next: NextFunction,@Req() req: Request,) {
     res.sendFile(join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'web', 'build', 'index.html'));
  }
```

In this route you can then add an auth guard or do a custom check and redirect or serve your index file.

Answer (score 0):

If your react app handles some routing then that approach will not work. Every time user navigates to /reactPath the controller serving index page will not be invoked. You need to handle all child routes.
To handle nested child routes with an arbitrary number of segments:

```
import { Controller, All, Req } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request } from 'express';

@Controller('myPath')
export class ParentController {
  @All('*')
  handleNestedChildRoute(@Req() request: Request) {
    // Extract the nested child route from the request url
    const nestedChildRoute = request.url.replace('/myPath/', '');
    
    // Your logic to handle all child routes nested under '/parent'
    return `Handled nested child route: ${nestedChildRoute}`;
  }
}
```